# How to run a .jar with admin privileges?

Tags: permissions, java, jar

I am attempting to open a .jar file with java 8 but it gives me an error message asking for admin privileges:

```
Please start the Authenticator with admin privileges
```

I am completely new to this type of issue, so my first reaction was to run `sudo java -jar /home/sethlord/Downloads/Authenticator/Authenticator.jar` in a terminal, but it gave me the same error message. Any fix?

Answer (score 3):

The classical method would be ...

```
sudo -i
java -jar /home/sethlord/Downloads/Authenticator/Authenticator.jar
```

If you really really need "root"

```
sudo -su
java -jar /home/sethlord/Downloads/Authenticator/Authenticator.jar
```

But try to avoid that since it logs notices to user "root" and not the "sudo" account.

Comment: I tried both of these, it simply gave the the same error message

Comment: Java is cross-platform. So it shouldn't matter.

Comment: where did you download it from @lokii google search did  not get me a result :P

Comment: https://mcleaks.net/authenticator maybe my mistake is really obvious, but like i said, im a noob

Comment: "Open the "MCLeaks Authenticator" folder and run following file:
- Windows users: MCLeaksAuthenticator.exe
- OSX users: Run Authenticator.command" You picked the windows or the Mac OS version?